# Jquery Datatable drag and drop rows

Tags: datatables

I implemented jquery datatables using

```
https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/select_row.html
```

Now I want to drag and drop rows.

I used jquery sortable and i did with normal table.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/mKaFe/126/
```

How can I implement that for jquery datatable.

Can it be achieved in jquery datatables?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Look at the Row Reordering plugin -> http://jquery-datatables-row-reordering.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply david.Its not working.If i try to drag and drop its coming to same position again

Comment: As you see in the example, and the [**wiki**](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-row-reordering/wiki/RowReordering) you must have an indexing column and each <tr> must have an ID. Unfortunetely there has never been made a more elegant plugin for dataTables regarding dragdrop row reordering.

Comment: Datatables support the row reordering with an additional plugin you can find on their website.
http://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/